# Use Preg_match for just for string inside two certain symbols

Tags: php

I'm trying to use preg_match just for string inside two certain symbols for example

```
My Name is %^i%Ibrahem ^i.
```

I want to use preg_match just for ^i which is inside this two symbols %% to be font-style:italic; I've tried:

```
$find=array('`\^i`si');
$replace=array('font-style:italic;');   
$replaced = preg_replace($find,$replace,$string);
```

but it replaces the last ^i too also keep in mind that the string between %% can be also %^b ^i% so I can't condition that the string have to be %^i% Help!

Comment: use the 4th argument to limit the number of replacements? `preg_replace($f, $r, $s, 1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this pattern instead:

```
$find = array('/%(.*?)(\^i)(.*?)%/', '/%(.*?)(\^b)(.*?)%/');
$replace = array('%$1font-style:italic;$3%', '%$1font-weight:bold;$3%');
$replaced = preg_replace('/%(.*)%/', '<span style="$1">', preg_replace($find, $replace, $string));
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add something that it maybe can be %^b ^i% ;')

Comment: What else could it be?

Comment: %^c:red; ^i ^n ^b% with different sorts. :3

Comment: I updated my pattern, it'll look for `%^i%` and `%^b ^i%`.

Comment: Is it in that specific order?

Comment: But If I change the sort to be %^i ^b% it won't work :(

Comment: Alright the regex should work for what you've provided to me and in any order! :)

Comment: I know that I'm annoying so much but, ^i have to be replace to font-style:italic; and ^b and other symbols must be replaced to another things like ^b to font-weight:bold; :(

Comment: I updated the code, and it should work for both ^i and ^b. Just add more to the array, and replace the (\^b) by what you want it to be.

Comment: You will kill me now :D Actually %% replace to <script style""> so all the symboles ^b ^i must be in the same string not in arrays if there were in array the code would include so much <script style"">

Comment: That's what it does though. Your initial line will become `My Name is %font-style:italic font-weight:bold%Ibrahem ^i.`

Comment: The code u provide wont do what I want, when I use <pre>preg_replace('\%(.*?)\%si', '<span style="$1">',$string);</pre> it will be `<span stlye="font-style:italic;"><span style="font-weight:bold;"> `But what I want is to be like this `<span style="font-style:italic font-weight:bold">`

Comment: There you go, it'll return `My Name is <span style="font-style:italic; font-weight:bold;">Ibrahem ^i.`

Comment: Thank you very much really, I bothered you so much :( forgive me for that.